# f-i.com png image... How do they do that?

Tags: javascript, png, transparent

how do they put the background transparent on that png file? If I load the image in photoshop, the image have a white background but that same image, on website, have transparent background.

Image
http://www.f-i.com/broadway/iPad/assets/images/design/ipad.png

Website
http://www.f-i.com/broadway/iPad/

Thanks

Comment: Save the file to your desktop and then open it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

This image has transparent background.

[image: This image has transparent background]

Besides your question is going out of the SO bounds, I'd suggest you to look at the [following thread of Photoshop community](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/opening_transparent_png_loses_transparency).

Comment: It sounded a little rude to me, also.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the image in Photoshop, can you make sure that you don't have a white background layer underneath your transparent image?

[image]